# How to set the image in button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have always this problem while working in android , and that is setting the image in the button. I have an image which I want to set in the button so I have multiple resolution of this button image for different buckets so to support multiple screen sizes .

Following is my image , having resolution of 85*85 
[image]

now when I want to set it in the button i got the image screw slightly. It seems like image in width is larger then the image in height where as it is not in reality. let me share you the picture after setting the image in the button. this screen short is of the android samsung galaxy s4 device which is xxhd device

[image]

Now you can easily see how bad it is looking .

this is how I am setting it in the xml

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/flip_image"
            />
```

but when I set this image in the Imageview every thing looks great as expected. so the problem is not in the image nor in the xml but the way in using the Button . So can any one tell me what is the best way of using the image in button or in Imagebutton .

**Please tell me why its happen all the time when I try to set image in button ,** whereas in the end when I use the imageview I always get my desired results.

> (How ever using Imageview make me loose the touch effect that the
>   button has naturally and by default.)

**Edit1 ** here is my part of xml where I am using buttons

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/menu_bg"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/flip_image"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_flip_suit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/flip_suit" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_change_suit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/change_suit" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_share"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:background="@drawable/share_btn" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
           />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:background="@drawable/save_image"

            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**So Any one please make me understand What i am doing wrong or what the best way of using Button with the custom image. ??**

Comment: You can use ImageButton

Comment: I mentioned in my question that I want to use Button , whereas using imageButton takes the transparent part of image inside also , which do not looks cool

Comment: "takes the transparent part of image inside also", could you clarify this?

Comment: I mean the image has corners , and it seems like button has padding in it  by default , Its my idea, something is there which is not letting the image to look proper as it should be, what I can guess best is , by default I think as button is rectangular , so there must be something which always tries button to be consistent in aspect ration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code, there is no problem in it...

As your image width problem, it is due to **Screen Resolution** on different devices, for that you can put your `Linear Layout` in `ScrollView`

your code output before scrollview :

[image: image1]

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/flip"> 
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

your output after scrollview :

[image: image 2]

Comment: are you trying to create menu with item arranged horizontally ?

Comment: try to change your  `TextView` `android:layout_width`

Comment: what was making buttons screw , ? and what helps after putting the scroll view , why it was not working before it

Comment: because it was fitting all button in present resolution so when resolution is high they fit good but when it is low it changes view `width` and `height` so they fit to screen ...when we provide scroll view it do not change view parameter, instead it extend them to view (beyond screen height)...      By definition : Layout container for a view hierarchy that can be scrolled by the user, allowing it to be larger than the physical display [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)

Comment: Got it , Although there is no need to use scroll bar as  these button must be fit to the half of the screen from the TOP

Comment: use `weight` to  fit them in your half screen ... but again here you have to use scroll view as you have 5 button with sufficient size...

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:src="@drawable/your_img" />
```

In this approach you could also use `ImageView` instead of `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

you can use

```
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for left side in button
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for top side in button
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for bottom side in button
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for right side in button
```

and your code is.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flip_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what are 
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for left side in button
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for top side in button
        android:drawableBottom="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for bottom side in button
        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"//image for rig

Comment: you can use android:drawableTop,Left,Right etc attribute of button which set image in button's specific position like top,left,right. and ic_launcher is my image which is set on button.

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:drawableTop` instead of `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use

```
android:drawableBottom ="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:drawableTop="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
 android:drawableRight="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
```

You can also try with ImageView instead of Button

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/flip_image" />
```

Comment: Use ImageView instead of button

Comment: yeah , I have mentioned it above

Comment: You have put images in respective folders like hdpi,mdpi... or use common ?

Comment: i have put specificly and accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I always use background as it doesnt change the image dimensions:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_flip_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/flip_image" />
```